# Is it possible to mimic nuts and bolts in blender using Normal maps?

Tags: texture-painting, normal-map

I've been wondering whether it is  possible to have fake nuts and bolts using Normal maps.

I know it is possible, but is there a way to just paint bolts wherever I want. I couldn't find any article regarding this.

Comment: here you can find solution to your problem
https://youtu.be/UFVdfvfLzU8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This video shows how to sort out normal maps to paint "bump".  If you use a an alpha brush/stencil you could paint "bump" bolts etc using texture paint, adding an extra "bump layer" (video etc). If you can find the free IK-brush kit for blender that's free online somewhere, it has bolts/screws heads etc in the brushes.  It may be wise to look up "normal map painting with alpha brushes" also.

https://youtu.be/svzKoq3vew0

Comment: you could just model the detail and bake it as a normal map, that could be easier.